google-navigation-flutter can't start with a custom point
I am developing an app with google-navigation-flutter. The plugin enable users to plan a route and navigate to the destination.
I want to reset the starting point in order to obtain a route between a custom starting point and the destination, rather than from the current location.
I tried to modify the example in the repo:flutter-navigation-sdk which fetched the routetoken using Routes API and pass it in RouteTokenOptions to use a specified starting point instead. However, it always started from my current location.

 Future<Destinations?> _buildDestinationsWithRoutesApi() async {
    assert(_routeTokensEnabled);

    showMessage('Using route token from Routes API.');

    List<String> routeTokens = <String>[];
    
    try {
      routeTokens = await getRouteToken(
        <NavigationWaypoint>[
          // Add users location as start location for getting routetoken.
          NavigationWaypoint.withLatLngTarget(
              title: 'Origin',
              target: LatLng(latitude: 24.2181, longitude: 120.7131)),  // change here
          // title: 'Origin', target: _userLocation),
          ..._waypoints,
        ],
      );
    } catch (e) {
      showMessage('Failed to get route tokens from Routes API. $e');
      return null;
    }

    if (routeTokens.isEmpty) {
      showMessage('Failed to get route tokens from Routes API.');
      return null;
    } else if (routeTokens.length > 1) {
      showMessage(
          'More than one route token received from Routes API. Using the first one.');
    }

    return Destinations(
        waypoints: _waypoints,
        displayOptions: NavigationDisplayOptions(showDestinationMarkers: false,),
        routeTokenOptions: RouteTokenOptions(
          routeToken: routeTokens.first, // Uses first fetched route token.
          travelMode: _travelMode,
        
        ));
  }


In the simulator, I set a current location different from the specified starting point (as shown in the image), but the result still shows a route starting from the current location. Is this the correct way to implement a custom starting point, or did I do something wrong?
enter image description here
enter image description here
